# Error generating web services through the Apache CXF framework

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web-services

I am trying to generate web services in Eclipse by using the Apache CXF framework.
First I am creating the Java class corresponding to the desired web service and then I generate two dynamic web projects, one for the web service (wsdl file) and another one for the clients. The web web services work well after I create them but after some time (one-three days) I get the error displayed in the image at the server startup.

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 7, 2011 9:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.4
Dec 7, 2011 9:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Prosys_Doctorat_Servicii_FAS_servicii\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Dec 7, 2011 9:27:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1672)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1028)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1028)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:592)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:418)
Dec 7, 2011 9:27:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Dec 7, 2011 9:27:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Then when I try to call a web service from the project I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at read_variable_value.ReadVariableNodeService1Service.<init>(ReadVariableNodeService1Service.java:50)
    at FAS.Model2_FAS.asociere_valori(Model2_FAS.java:206)
    at FAS.Model2_FAS.main(Model2_FAS.java:2596)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:8081/Prosys_Doctorat_Servicii_FAS_servicii/services/ReadVariableNodeService1Port?wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8081/Prosys_Doctorat_Servicii_FAS_servicii/services/ReadVariableNodeService1Port?wsdl
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:91)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8081/Prosys_Doctorat_Servicii_FAS_servicii/services/ReadVariableNodeService1Port?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

What can cause this error which only appears after the web services are used repeatedly?

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mTNZ.jpg
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYkQb.jpg

---

**Hi, the client is automatically generated in the following way:**

```
private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new  QName("http://read_variable/", "ReadVariableNodeServiceService");
URL wsdlURL = ReadVariableNodeServiceService.WSDL_LOCATION;
ReadVariableNodeServiceService ss = new ReadVariableNodeServiceService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
SEIReadValue port = ss.getReadVariableNodeServicePort();  
      {
        System.out.println("Invoking getValue...");
        java.lang.String _getValue_arg0 = "Alina";
        java.lang.String _getValue_arg1 = "WorkspaceS1";
        try {
            double _getValue__return = port.getValue(_getValue_arg0, _getValue_arg1);
            System.out.println("getValue.result=" + _getValue__return);
        ................
```

**Last week I have found an interesting documentation which recommends the following way to call a web service:**

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"read_variable/client3_beans.xml"});
    SEIReadValue port = (SEIReadValue) context.getBean("readvariableClient");
{
    System.out.println("Invoking getValue...");
    java.lang.String _getValue_arg0 = "Alina";
    java.lang.String _getValue_arg1 = "WorkspaceS1";
    try {
        double _getValue__return = port.getValue(_getValue_arg0, _getValue_arg1);
        System.out.println("getValue.result=" + _getValue__return);
        .........
```

**What do you think? May this be the reason for my error?**

---

I am very happy that I have almost found out the cause of my error. But I am  a beginner in web services and I haven't understood your message entirely.
I want to specify that I have a set of basic/simple web services, and then based on these web services I have created a complex web service where I obtain the context
of each simple web service in order to obtain its functionality, and as you said (as I understood) this is not the right approach.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"write_a_matrix/client2_beans.xml"});
SEIWriteMatrix port = (SEIWriteMatrix) context.getBean("write_a_matrix_Client");
...........................................................
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context_WV=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"write_value/client1_beans.xml"});
SEIWriteValue port_WV = (SEIWriteValue) context_WV.getBean("write_a_value_Client");
...........................................................
```

I have created a client_beans xml file for each web service client. Is it ok? Can you provide me an example of how to call a web service and the way to hold just one App context?

I will provide you my email address < berlindutza@yahoo.com > in case you want to communicate much easier because I have seen that we are limited to a certain number of characters (for the *add comment* section).

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here: You are probably recreating the CXF client for every request, instead of creating it once, keeping it as a singleton and using this one instance for every subsequent request.

Ideally you should be able to generate the client using the webservice interface. If you have explicitly specified a wsdl, cxf will generate a proxy based on the WSDL, which is what seems to be happening for you. Once in a while the service which serves out the wsdl fails and you get this error.

If you are using Spring, you can do something along these lines:

```
<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="...wsInterface" />
    <property name="address" value="serviceURL" />
</bean>

<bean id="client" class="...wsInterface" factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create" />
```

Comment: Hi

Thank you for your answer. 
I generate my web services in the following way. First I write the service class and then right click on it -> Web Services -> Create Web Services. And I generate the WSDL,the SEI and the client in two separate projects. 
I have seen that beans.xml and web.xml are generated in the service dynamic web project but in the client project I couldn't find the file client-beans.xml.

Could this be the error? Shoud I add the file client-beans.xml as displayed below?

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"...<jaxws:client 
             id="readvariableClient" 
      serviceClass="read_variable_value.SEI_obtainV"
      address="http://localhost:8081/Prosys_Doctorat_FAS2_servicii/services/ReadVariableNodeService1Port"
 />
 
</beans>

Comment: That looks good Girbea, can you also show me how you get an instance of readVariableClient in your code.

Comment: Looked at your sample that you have provided - that is the reason for the error @GirbeaAlina, you should be instantiating the Application once, and use the beans from this one context to make the call. In your case, you are actually creating the Application Context for every call, and that recreates the entire CXF client for every call, and if the service exposing the wsdl happens to be down, is not able to create the client at that time and hence the error. If you are calling via a web application, there are ways to hold just one App context, similarly for a standalone app.